# Check if Parse.com field is undefined/nil ?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, undefined

In parse when you have a field for data, let's say a string, to check if there is no data in it, you have to click on the field to remove the "undefined", then in Xcode do:

```
if(myString.isEmpty){/*do something*/}
```

If I try to simply compare it to nil, I get the error: "Binary operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type string and nil"

I am making an app that retrieves several objects from Parse.com, I want to be able to constantly update my app from there, what I have not been able to figure out is how to add checks for a field that is undefined, sometimes I want to be able to leave some of the data fields undefined because not all of them are crucial, so how would I achieve this?

There is the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038452/parse-com-how-to-properly-check-if-a-field-is-empty), but what the user asking used to solve his problem, did not work for me

Answer (score 3):

you can do optional binding

```
if let name = employerProfileObject.valueForKey("name"){
      self.companyIndustry.text = "\(name.capitalizedString)"
}
```

it wont return an error if the field in parse is empty